# Using replace() for character replacement in a textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, translation

I'm having trouble building this tool that helps with character for character translation. So far, I have this:

```
<form>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" onkeyup="replacer('englishform')" onkeydown="replacer('englishform')" placeholder="Enter English" rows="15"></textarea>
</form>
<form>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="albhedform" placeholder="Enter Al Bhed" rows="15"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want to have the text entered into englishform stay the same and the replace happen in the albhedform. So this would be something similar to how google translate responds when people type in one box or the other.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function replacer(e){
    var english = document.getElementById(e);
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');

    english.value = english.value.replace(/a/g, "y");   
    english.value = english.value.replace(/b/g, "p");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/c/g, "l");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/d/g, "t");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/e/g, "a");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/f/g, "v");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/g/g, "k");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/h/g, "r");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/i/g, "e");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/j/g, "z");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/k/g, "g");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/l/g, "m");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/m/g, "s");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/n/g, "h");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/o/g, "u");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/p/g, "b");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/q/g, "x");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/r/g, "n");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/s/g, "c");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/t/g, "d");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/u/g, "i");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/v/g, "j");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/w/g, "f");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/x/g, "q");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/y/g, "o");
    english.value = english.value.replace(/z/g, "w");
    }
/* I thought this would work in moving the replaced text to the albhedform, but it doesn't */
/*
    english.onkeyup = function() {
    albhed.value = english.value;
    };
*/

</script>
```

With every new keystroke, all the characters are being replaced again causing the translation to be wrong. What am I missing? Should I have to create an array with key value pairs for the character for character translation?

Thanks to @Me.Name, I have it working a little better now, but I'm still missing the translation.

Look at the code below:

```
<form>

    <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" onkeyup="replacer('englishform')" onkeydown="replacer('englishform')" placeholder="Enter English" rows="15"></textarea><br />
</form>
<form>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="albhedform" placeholder="Enter Al Bhed" rows="15"></textarea>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function replacer(e){
    var replacement = ['y', 'p', 'l', 't', 'a', 'v', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'z', 'g', 'm', 's', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'x', 'n', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'q', 'o', 'w']; 
    var english = document.getElementById(e);
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');
    albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, replacement/*here is the issue */); 
}
</script>
```

So the issue is with the latter part of the replace() method. I can't seem to get the regex brackets to be replaced letter for letter using "c => replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]"

```
albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you are retranslating letters you already translated, so better would be to just use other variable to store results and not mutate your value

Comment: @Kejt Do you mean a new function for every character? such as:     `function replacer(a){};    function replacer(b){};     function replacer(c){};...` and so on? and within each function, should I only use 1 `English.value = english.value.replace(/a/g, "y");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two-fold: first is that the original text is being replaced in each (sub) replace action with `english.value=`. The second is that by doing the replacements in steps, previous replacements can be uhm... rereplaced.

One option is to use a replacer function to replace in regex. For this a lookup table could be used for all characters. e.g. the following creates a Map with all the required replacements:

```
var replacements = new Map(Array.from({length:26},  (v,i)=> [String.fromCharCode(97 + i), 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'[i] ]));
```

This could be used in a regex replacer, (or by mapping all the chars):

```
albhedform.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacements.get(c.toLowerCase()) || c);
```

Unfold the snippet below for an example

```js
var replacements = new Map(Array.from({length:26},  (v,i)=> [String.fromCharCode(97 + i), 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow'[i] ]));

function replacer(english){
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');
    
    albhedform.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacements.get(c.toLowerCase()) || c);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" onkeyup="replacer(this)"  placeholder="Enter English" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
<form>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="albhedform" placeholder="Enter Al Bhed" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

---

Or if only the alphabet is needed (and no other chars are needed in the future), it could be further simplified by simply keeping a string for each letter

```
var replacements = 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow';
//.....
//function
    albhedform.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]);
```

```js
var replacements = 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow';

function replacer(english){
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');    
    albhedform.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" onkeyup="replacer(this)"  placeholder="Enter English" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
<form>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="albhedform" placeholder="Enter Al Bhed" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I see a few mistakes in your answer, but even when I fix the known mistakes, it still won't print anything. The first one is that `albhedform.value = english.value.replace(...)` should be `albhed.value = english.value.replace(...)` and the html form should have `onkeyup="replacer('englishform')"` I have everything working except the translation. I created a variable with `var replacement = ['y', 'p', 'l', 't', 'a', 'v', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'z', 'g', 'm', 's', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'x', 'n', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'q', 'o', 'w'];` because `var replacements = 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow';` isn't working

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the issue seems to be with `c => replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]` and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Ah the `albhedform.value` was mixed up somewhere with copy/pasting. (Should still work on most browsers, because `albhedform` is a direct reference to the element with that id). The `replacer(this)` was actually intentionally, because now the function is called with a string with its own name that is processed again. Wanted to show in the example that the call can be done directly using the element itself. About why it isn't working is hard to say without example. Perhaps ES6 is the problem and `function(c){return replacements[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97];}` should be used instead

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that shows how typing a word in the top textarea does nothing but display the text typed. https://jsfiddle.net/p2hjzvbc/8/

Comment: The variable was called `replacement`, but the function used `replacements`, here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2hjzvbc/9/  (PS, also removed the script tags. and set the 'load type' of the fiddle to 'no wrap in. The default for a fiddle is 'onload', but then the declared functions are not directly accessible from the html )

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been a great help.

Comment: NP, glad it was of help :)